# Циклы и переменные в imacros

Tags: imacros

Есть запись макроса в imacros:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_49
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_51
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_53
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_55
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_57
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_59
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_61
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_63
```

Как видно, меняется лишь последние цифры.
Как сделать цикл с шагом цикла в 2 единицы и подстановку переменной в конец?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос с циклом так для себя не решил, а вот с подстановкой регулярного значения вопрос закрыл.

В iMacros есть 3 переменные !VAR1, !VAR2 и !VAR3, а так же команда сложения ADD.

Вот как будет выглядеть упомянутый выше код с использованием этих возможностей:

SET !VAR1 49 'задаем стартовое значение переменной, т.е. 49

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_{{!VAR1}}

ADD !VAR1 2 'прибавляем значению переменной 2, т.е. 49+2=51

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_{{!VAR1}}

ADD !VAR1 2 'прибавляем значению переменной 2, т.е. 51+2=53

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_{{!VAR1}}

Answer (score 1):

циклом это делается так

SET !LOOP 0

SET INIT 49

SET STEP 2

SET VALUE EVAL("{{INIT}}+{{STEP}}*{{!LOOP}}")

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/reqs.php ATTR=ID:uup5vx_{{VALUE}}